# NSNetServiceBrowser not finding services that exist

Tags: objective-c, macos, bonjour, nsnetservicebrowser

I have a custom Cocoa (OSX) server and client, and the server publishes a bonjour service. I have the client searching for the server using `NSNetServiceBrowser`, but I never get any results. I know that the service is published because it is in the output of `mdns -B _myservicetype._tcp`. My searching and publishing code both search and publish with the same domain, name, and type, and are almost identical to the Apple sample code. Here's the publishing code:

```
service = [[NSNetService alloc] initWithDomain:@"" type:@"_scijs._tcp" name:@"ScienceJeopardyServer" port:4567];
[service publish];
```

And here's the search and delegate methods:

```
[sbrows setDelegate:self];
[sbrows searchForServicesOfType:@"_scijs._tcp" inDomain:@""];
```

And here are the delegate methods:

```
-(void)netServiceBrowserWillSearch:(NSNetServiceBrowser *)aNetServiceBrowser {
    [self.statusLabel setStringValue:@"Searching for server..."];
    [self.serverIndicator setHidden:NO];
    [self.serverIndicator startAnimation:self];
}

-(void)netServiceBrowser:aNetServiceBrowser didNotSearch:(NSDictionary *)errorDict {
    [self.statusLabel setStringValue:@"Error finding server."];
    [self.serverIndicator stopAnimation:self];
    [self.serverIndicator setHidden:YES];
}

-(void)netServiceBrowserDidStopSearch:(NSNetServiceBrowser *)aNetServiceBrowser {
    [self.serverIndicator stopAnimation:self];
    [self.serverIndicator setHidden:YES];
}

-(void)netServiceBrowser:(NSNetServiceBrowser *)aNetServiceBrowser didFindService:(NSNetService *)aNetService moreComing:(BOOL)moreComing {
    [aNetServiceBrowser stop];
    NSLog(@"Found server.");
    [self.statusLabel setStringValue:@"Resolving service..."];
    [aNetService setDelegate:self];
    [aNetService resolveWithTimeout:10.0];
}
```

Most of it's just GUI code and NSLogs, yet I never get the gui changes or the NSLogs. Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are it's in your client.

1. Set breakpoints in the delegate methods.
2. Make sure `sbrows` isn't falling out of scope. If it falls out of scope willSearch gets called then no other responses.

Comment: Thanks so much, turned out to be a subtle ARC issue with scope. +1 and accept!

Comment: So how did you fix this? I'm having the exact same problem.