# NSNetServiceBrowser cannot find any service, the delegate method does not seems to be called

Tags: ios, bonjour, nsnetservicebrowser

I am using NSNetServiceBrowser to browse bonjour service. The service is started successfully, however, I am facing an issue while browsing the service. When I make the call `searchForServicesOfType:inDomain`, only the `netServiceBrowserWillSearch` delegate method is called. No other delegate method is called and I cant find any service. The answer seems to be given by this guy here, [NSNetServiceBrowser not finding services that exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13332965/nsnetservicebrowser-not-finding-services-that-exist) but I cant understand what does he actually means (see part 2 of the answer). The author of the question solved the problem but he didnt elaborated. Please tell me why the other delegate methods like `netServiceBrowser:didFindService:moreComing:` are not called
Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: If one delegate is getting called, then other one should be called unless you are not explicitly using `setDelegate:toSomeOtherClass`

Comment: I think that guy told that some class has been silently deallocated due to some ARC issue . I would add "and set to nil what ARC can do in some circumstances". In that case no further delegate methods will be called. Unfortunately I cannot tell you what class would it be.

Comment: Hi abbas, I am facing same problem as you mentioned at above. please tell me the how to solve this problem.